# Create mobile app using 2g networks

Tags: android, html, networking, gprs

I want to create android mobile application that uses GPRS. How to create such applications? 
Is it possible to use html5 to do that application? 
I want to send/receive the data through GPRS. Therefore how is it possible? Are there any samples or references to d such apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPRS is just another type of Internet connection as far as you are concerned, just develop a regular app that requires data transfers.